# Does creating functions inside functions have a recurring cost?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a function in Python that I'm planning to run for 10 000 or more times for each script execution. The function currently contains 3 sub-functions but will probably contain 20 or more when the script is complete. I'm just wondering; Will declaring those functions over and over (since the parent function will be run thousands of times) have a recurring performance cost, or is that optimised and not an issue?

**Would separating all those sub-functions into a class help with performance?**

*(I intend to test this and post the results here if nobody knows the answer on the top of their heads.)*

Comment: Why not simply move them outside the "parent" function?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Well, because there's so many of them, and they can't possibly have any purpose outside of the parent function. I don't like to clutter my modules.

Comment: kind of related :[classes-vs-functions](http://goo.gl/HdW07)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The performance impact of a function definition is negligible and comparable to defining a local variable.

The body of the function is compiled only once, all that you end up with during execution of the code-block is loading the compiled block (`LOAD_CONST`), and the result of the `MAKE FUNCTION` byte code is then stored in a local variable:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     def bar():
...         pass
...     print 'boo!'
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object bar at 0x106c447b0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (bar)

  4           9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('boo!')
             12 PRINT_ITEM          
             13 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now, if you call that function containing nested functions thousands of times, you do notice a performance impact for that `MAKE_FUNCTION` operation:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def nonlocal(): pass
... 
>>> def callnonlocal(): nonlocal()
... 
>>> def calllocal():
...     def localf(): pass
...     localf()
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('callnonlocal()', 'from __main__ import callnonlocal')
0.39106082916259766
>>> timeit.timeit('calllocal()', 'from __main__ import calllocal')
0.4878239631652832
```

Do note that that difference will get smaller the more *actual code* you put into your functions though. The above examples are very contrived and focus solely on the impact of `MAKE_FUNCTION` byte code on execution times.

Better optimize for readability and maintainability first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, defining a function inside another function has a slight performance penalty over defining functions at module scope.